# Is there something like stylesheet_url on Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets

I want to use application.css on my email templates, but I can't find a way to make the stylesheet_link_tag helper to include the full url of the stylesheet so email clients can render properly.

By default, stylesheet_link_tag only adds the relative path, so, I want to know if there is a way to either tell stylesheet_link_tay to use the url, or a helper that returns the url to the stylesheet.

This is for Rails 3.1, by the way

Answer (score 0):

You may consider that the `<link rel=stylesheet>` isn't supported by the mayor providers like Hotmail, Gmail and Yahoo: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

The best option that you have is using `<styles>` tags in your body or header; or even uglier, using the inline styles, that is supported by most of the email clients today.

> Google Mail, in particular, looks for STYLE anywhere in the email and (helpfully) deletes it. And don’t bother to use CSS LINK to a stylesheet. Google Mail, Hotmail, and other email software ignore, modify, or delete these external references to a stylesheet.

http://www.reachcustomersonline.com/2011/12/21/09.27.00/

Answer (score 0):

Rails 3.1 uses asset pipeline. If you are using asset pipeline then you need to mention those assets in you application.css. For example in application.css

```
/*
* *application.css
*= require scaffold
*= require pagination
*= require_self
*= require_tree.
*/
```

In the above scaffold and pagination should be under rails_root/app/assets/stylesheets ditrectory. For more info check this out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Or if asset pipeline is not your issue then check this railcast for HTML Email.
http://railscasts.com/episodes/312-sending-html-email?view=asciicast

Answer (score 0):

you can specify the full path of your assets by using

config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://www.yourdomainFORassets.com"

in your environment config file

And you better be careful with the images URL inside CSS files, I have to move everything
to this way to use existing code, check http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html
specially with this part:

2.2.2 CSS and Sass

When using the asset pipeline, paths to assets must be re-written and sass-rails provides -url and -path helpers (hyphenated in Sass, underscored in Ruby) for the following asset classes: image, font, video, audio, JavaScript and stylesheet.

```
image-url("rails.png") becomes url(/assets/rails.png)
image-path("rails.png") becomes "/assets/rails.png".
```

The more generic form can also be used but the asset path and class must both be specified:

```
asset-url("rails.png", image) becomes url(/assets/rails.png)
asset-path("rails.png", image) becomes "/assets/rails.png"
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production

Regards